# Join data from ZonalStatistics output to original zone shapefile?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am currently using arcpy to compute zonal statistics (mean) for a large number of polygons and a raster file using the following function

```
in_polys = some_shapefile
in_raster = some_raster

arcpy.ZonalStatistics(in_polys, "some_field", in_raster, statistics_type = "MEAN")
```

This produces the desired raster with the appropriate values. However, I wish to "join" the average values in the raster to the original zone shapefile to this effect:

```
ID Year  MEAN
1  2001  3.2
2  2002  1.2
3  2003  7.2
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this **in arcpy**?

Comment: I think you can do that with `ZonalStatisticsAsTable`